# Vuex Sockets with Node.js

Tags: vuex

I'm using vuex with socket on ubuntu and mac.

when i return data object from server socket (node.js), the socket get different data for each operation system:
- ubuntu data returns array with the object in his first element
- mac data returns the object itself

i don't understand why it return different structure for the same data object and what can i do to change it.

server:

```
data = { data: elements, actionType, actionStatus }    
this.socket.emit('dataUpdate', data)
```

vuex mutation:

```
  SOCKET_DATAUPDATE: (state, data) => {
  state.lastAction.status = data[0].actionStatus || false
  state.lastAction.type = data[0].actionStatus === 'done' ? null : 
  data[0].actionType
  if (!data[0].data) return
  // add node if not exist or merge if it does
  data[0].data.forEach(newD => {
    const index = state.data.findIndex(d => d.data.id === 
    newD.data.id)
    index === -1 ? state.data.push(newD) : state.data[index] = newD
  })
}
```

tnx :)